# Search within a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a list containing the following structure.

```
class CompareDesignGroup
{
    string FieldId;
    string Caption;
}
```

The list is containing items of the above structure.

Is it possible to retrieve an element of the list if FieldId is known?

Comment: use Linq to retrive the Data.

Comment: var resultingList = listOfYourClasses.Where(item=>item.FieldId == yourFieldIdOfInterest).ToList();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Find method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) on the generic list class. The find method takes a predicate that lets you filter/search the list for  a single item.

```
List<CompareDesignGroup> list = // ..;
CompareDesignGroup item = list.Find(c => c.FieldId == "SomeFieldId");
```

`item` will be null if there is no matching item in the list.

If you need to find more than one item you can use the [FindAll method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z):

```
List<CompareDesignGroup> list = // ..;
List<CompareDesignGroup> result= list.FindAll(c => c.FieldId == "SomeFieldId");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Where` and then you can use `FirstOrDefault`. That is an [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) expression.

```
var ls = new List<CompareDesignGroup>();
var result = ls.Where(a => a.FieldId=="123").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or `SingleOrDefault` to get the item you want. Like this:

```
var ls = new List<CompareDesignGroup>();
var result = ls.Where(a => a.FieldId=="123").SingleOrDefault()
```

Or even simpler:

```
var result = ls.SingleOrDefault(a => a.FieldId=="123");
var result2 = ls.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FieldId=="123");
```

Comment: this will not return element of list like OP asked.

Comment: You can omit the Where and put the predicate directly in `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) or the built-in functionalities of `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ like this:

```
CompareDesignGroup result = yourList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldId == yourKnownId);
```

If you use the `FirstOrDefault` method the `result` will be `null` when list doesn't contain a record with a known id. So before using `result` check if it is not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a plethora of methods to find an item inside a list.

[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926) provides extensions method useful to work with collections that does not provide their own search features (or when you do not have the collection itself but a generic interface like `IEnumerable<T>`). If you have a `List<CompareDesignGroup>` object and you'll work on that object you can use the methods provided by that class ([specialized methods are almost always faster than LINQ methods](http://codebetter.com/stevehebert/2008/02/06/linq-to-objects-relating-data-structure-organization-to-where-clause-optimization/), they know collection's internal structure and does not have to rely on many abstraction layers).

In all examples I'll perform a culture invariant and case sensitive comparison for `FieldId` to a hypothetical `id` parameter. This may not be what you need and you may have to change according to your requirements.

### Using `List<T>`

Given a list declared as:

```
List<CompareDesignGroup>() list = new List<CompareDesignGroup>();
```

To find **first** element that matches the search criteria (it'll return `null` if no items have been found):

```
CompareDesignGroup item = list.Find(
    x => String.Equals(x.FieldId, id,  StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

To find **all** the elements that matches the search criteria:

```
List<CompareDesignGroup> items = list.FindAll(
    x => String.Equals(x.FieldId, id,  StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

### Using `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IList<T>`, for example)

Given a list declared as:

```
IEnumerable<CompareDesignGroup> list = ...
```

To find **first** element that matches the search criteria (`null` if no items have been found):

```
CompareDesignGroup item = list.FirstOrDefault(
    x => String.Equals(x.FieldId, id,  StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

To find the **first** element that matches the search criteria (or throw an exception if no items have been found):

```
CompareDesignGroup item = list.First(
    x => String.Equals(x.FieldId, id,  StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

To find **all** elements that matches the search criteria:

```
IEnumerable<CompareDesignGroup> item = list.Where(
    x => String.Equals(x.FieldId, id,  StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

There are many LINQ extensions methods, I suggest to take a look to them all to find the one that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<CompareDesignGroup> listData = new List<CompareDesignGroup>(); // init the data
var result = listData.Where(x=> String.Equals(x.FieldID,"FIELDID KNOWN VALUE"); // gets all data
var first = listData.FirstOrDefault(x=> String.Equals(x.FieldID,"FIELDID KNOWN VALUE"); // gets first search result
```